# react-native-onesignal does transmit the data but no notification showed

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, onesignal

I have followed all the steps required to integrate with iOS currently this is my code on index.ios.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native'
import wrapper from './wrapper'
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal'

let pendingNotifications = [];

function handleNotification (notification) { // If you want to handle the notifiaction with a payload.
        // _navigator.to('main.post', notification.data.title, {
        //  article: {
        //    title: notification.data.title,
        //    link: notification.data.url,
        //    action: notification.data.actionSelected
        //  }
        //});
        console.log("handle notification data:", notification)
}

OneSignal.configure({
        onIdsAvailable: function(device) {
                console.log('UserId = ', device.userId);
                console.log('PushToken = ', device.pushToken);
        },
    onNotificationOpened: function(message, data, isActive) {
            var notification = {message: message, data: data, isActive: isActive};
            console.log('NOTIFICATION OPENED: ', notification);
            //if (!_navigator) { // Check if there is a navigator object. If not, waiting with the notification.
            //    console.log('Navigator is null, adding notification to pending list...');
                    pendingNotifications.push(notification);
            //    return;
            // }
            handleNotification(notification);
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('pvj', () => wrapper)
```

actually all the console.log message is triggered on xcode log when a message sent from onesignal dashboard, but not a notification...

2016-08-27 23:41:38.536 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'NOTIFICATION OPENED: ', { message: 'Mungkin harus di link ke Push Notificationnya si react-native kali ya',
  data: { sound: 'default', title: 'Ah Gila Ini Susah Banget' },
  isActive: true }

2016-08-27 23:41:38.537 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'handle notification data:', { message: 'Mungkin harus di link ke Push Notificationnya si react-native kali ya',
  data: { sound: 'default', title: 'Ah Gila Ini Susah Banget' },
  isActive: true }

does this plugin require further integration with PushNotificationIOS?

Thank You